# how to edit/view/access the var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin

Tags: package-management, database, metadata

as the **pkgcache.bin** and **scrpkgcache.bin** in the folder /var/cache/apt/
contains detail information about any package, can I access to these files to edit or copy information?

Comment: I think `apt-cache` does this, at least copy but I doubt you can modify any pkg that is yours!

Comment: As everything in `/var/cache/` this should not be touched. What are you exactly trying to do? Why do you want to edit informations about any package? As to list, start with `dpkg --get-selections`